# Outlook Web App can't access another user mailbox, Outlook 2010 can

Tags: outlook-2010, outlook-web-app, mailbox

In our office some of our employees use Outlook from Office 2010, while others use the Outlook Web App.
In my team me and a colleague use the Web App and Outlook side-by-side for testing, while others only use Outlook. We have a mailbox called `"serviceandsupport"`, it's not a shared mailbox but a normal user mailbox that everyone in my team can access, **but only when using Outlook**. We can add the mailbox in the Web App and it is shown below our own mailbox, but when we try to open it the Web App returns an error `"can't complete your request" - "you might not have permission to perform this action"`. Weird thing is, when I open the mailbox in Outlook it doesn't give any errors.

What could cause such an error to appear only in the Web App and not in Outlook?

Comment: How was permission granted to your team to access the mailbox? The output of `Get-MailboxPermission | fl` would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

OWA may be disabled for the mailbox. Have a check in Exchange Management Console, Mailbox preperties, tab Mailbox Feature, check if Outlook Web App is enabled.